# Applying netplan with both NetworkManager and networkd

Tags: networking, network-manager, administration, systemd-networkd

I have the following question: how does `sudo netplan apply` work when it has several configuration files with different renderers: e.g. I have 2 config files in `/etc/netplan`:

**01-network-manager.yaml**

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

**99_config.yaml**

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:

    eno1:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.220.1/24

    # 10Gbit - optical
    enp3s0f0:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.1.20/24
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [15.20.222.162]

    # 10Gbit - optical
    enp3s0f1:
      link-local: [ ipv4 ]
```

According to the information I found online, there cannot be two renderers at the same time. Moreover, I found that `sudo netplan apply` will try to combine all the configuration files into one. So, how will this conflict resolve?

Comment: What is the purpose of the Ntework Manager yaml? If it is not intended to be effective, simply remove it. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The YAML that is processed later will win. It's that simple.

The files will be processed in alphanumeric numeric order (01- before 99_) during startup.

Therefore YAML in 01- will be processed first. But any fields that disagree will be superseded (or overridden) by YAML in 99_ . Any fields that don't disagree will remain.

In the specific example you offered, networkd will be the renderer.

Comment: thank you very much! Very clear. This pretty much answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    enp1s0:
      renderer: NetworkManager
    enp2s0:
      renderer: networkd
      dhcp4: true
```

Comment: Are you sure this syntax is working?

Comment: sure. tested on ubuntu 22.04 yesterday.

Comment: https://netplan.readthedocs.io/en/stable/netplan-yaml/#properties-for-all-device-types

Each device is allowed to have their own renderer as specified in the documentation.